# Random number not from array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a random number that is not equal to any number in my array_Block01. I seem to only find a randon number within my array, but how do I find a number outside my array?

```
var array_Block01 = []
  while(array_Block01.length < 9){
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*9) + 1;
      if(array_Block01.indexOf(r) === -1) array_Block01.push(r);
  }
RandomValue = array_Block01[Math.floor(Math.random()*array_Block01.length)];
```

Comment: You're accessing index of `array_Block1` and you expecting values out of `array_Block1` ?

Comment: I get array_Block01 with 9 different integers using above code. I did not understand what else is required. Can you please add current and expected output?

Comment: I am trying to find a random integer outside of array_block01 between 1 and 18.

Comment: I am currently getting only a random number 1-9 from my current array, but I am trying to find a number (between a range of 1-18) outside this array.

Comment: Or maybe easier trying to find a random value (1-9) from the following array that is not included in the following array.:

var array_Block01 = [1,,5,2,,,,7,3,,]
RandomValue = array_Block01[Math.floor(Math.random()*array_Block01.length)];

Comment: with `array_Block01[Math.floor(Math.random()*array_Block01.length)];`, you are generating a random index only, and getting the value at that index from `array_Block01`. This is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the code to do that -

```
var array_Block01 = []
  while(array_Block01.length < 9){
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*9) + 1;
      if(array_Block01.indexOf(r) === -1) array_Block01.push(r);
  }
function getRandomExceptArray(arr){
    while(true){    
        let randValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18); //18 is upper limit
        if(randValue !==0 && arr.indexOf(randValue) === -1) return randValue;
    }
}
RandomValue = getRandomExceptArray(array_Block01);
```